# PostgreSQL: Converting data file string to epoch time

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, epoch

I'm attempting to convert an epoch string value (listed as 'updated_date') within a data field to epoch time. See the output listed below: 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Here is a snippet of the query:

```
select created_at
      ,data -> 'skill_survey_recent_status' as status
      ,data -> 'skill_survey_recent_status_date' as updated_date 
from line_items 
where product_id = 2
order by 1 desc
```

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean with "epoch time", but to convert that to a proper timestamp value, use [`to_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html):

```
select created_at, 
       data -> 'skill_survey_recent_status' as status
       to_timestamp((data -> 'skill_survey_recent_status_date')::double precision) as updated_date 
from line_items 
where product_id = 2
order by 1 desc
```